# Why is the nuclear norm called so?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, math-history, nuclear-norm

A simple question. Why is the sum of the singular values of a matrix called its [nuclear norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Schatten_norms)? What is the origin of, and motivation for, this term?

Apparently the term *nucleus* is sometimes used to refer to the kernel of a linear transformation, but that doesn't seem to have anything to do with singular values.

To save you the effort, neither *nucleus* nor *nuclear* have entries in [*Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics*](http://jeff560.tripod.com/n.html).

Comment: It is related to the norm of nuclear operators; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_operator#On_Banach_spaces these get their name because they generalize operators given by kernels.

Comment: There is a new SE network; history of science and math. hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: -----> [History of science and math](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Mariano: Ah, so it's a 20th-century development, which explains why it isn't in *Earliest Known Uses*. I should have thought to check *Encyclopedia of Math*, which [does mention the connection straight away](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Nuclear_norm). Is it common in mathematics to use *nucleus* as a synonym for *kernel*, or to describe things related to kernels as *nuclear*?

Comment: Fun story: One of my professors once travelled to USSR. At the border, their baggage was checked -- in particular their scientific papers. Then, they were arrested for a short time, because they worked with "Nuclear operators" without declaring it beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mariano explains in a comment that the nuclear norm is related to the norm of [nuclear operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_operator#On_Banach_spaces), which in turn get their name because they generalize operators given by kernels.

There is [a lot more information on nuclear operators](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Nuclear_operator) at the *Encyclopedia of Mathematics*.